# FormArray is getting populated with duplicate controls

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

So, I have a list component which has an child component in the view template.
which is looped with the list observable using async pipe.
now I introduce a search control which filter out the list using it's name & it's working fine
but when I remove the search value from the control the form array is getting duplicate controls.

I have to try to reset the form array when search for a value but didn't get anything.

I have created a bare minimum demo component of what my actual component looks just for the better reference what I'm doing:
Here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/wonderful-james-fdjly2?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsuby629000628686izgtrde%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsuby6290002286864a1qb9v%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsuby62900042868wkmdu4jg%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsuby62900052868bhy6hjgh%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clsuby6290002286864a1qb9v%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsuby6290002286864a1qb9v%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clsuby62900052868bhy6hjgh%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsuby62900052868bhy6hjgh%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A4200%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsufx0yn012q2867ifhusrpn%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsufx0yn012q2867ifhusrpn%2522%257D%252C%2522clsuby62900042868wkmdu4jg%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsuby62900042868wkmdu4jg%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsuby629000328688wpfue8w%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsuby629000328688wpfue8w%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) link.
Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. enter 'config' in the input.
2. now clear the input & hit the save button.
3. you can see the duplicate values in the console.
4. open sanbox view in the new tab & click on the inspect element you can see the console value of form array there.

Comment: Your StackBlitz link didn't show as what you mentioned with duplicate control. Also, you should post a minimal, reproducible example in the question instead of providing the link only.

Comment: Sorry, I have now updated with the working issue example. Please have a look.

Comment: @MohitPandey It still does not work!

Comment: @MohitPandey, no, click the Sandbox link and get message: "It's likely that the Sandbox you're trying to access doesn't exist or you don't have the required permissions to access it.".

Comment: Please have a look now.

Comment: I imagine you should use `merge` (that return one observable **or** another one), not `combineLatest`

Comment: @Eliseo I think the problem is with the configs observable whenever it gets changed it also re run the config component which then push form group to the form array. I'm able to debug the problem but can't able to find solution until now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `ConfigComponent`, each time the (root) input field changes, it will push the `FormGroup` into `FormArray`. That results in your `FormArray`  value is not correct as what is displayed in the view.

Would suggest your `ConfigComponent` should handle for the (single) `config` `FormGroup` only, not to handle the `FormArray`.

*config-list.component.ts* Changes:

1. After filtering the values for the `config` observable, clear the existing `pages` `FormArray` and bind with the filtered array values.
2. Add `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` into the `@Component` decorator to prevent the "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError" error.

```
import {
  Observable,
  combineLatest,
  map,
  of,
  startWith,
  tap
} from 'rxjs';
import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-config-lists',
  templateUrl: './config-lists.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class ConfigListsComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchFacebookConfig();
    this.setupIntegration();

    this.configs = combineLatest([
      this.pageAccessTokenConfig,
      this.searchConfigControl.valueChanges.pipe(startWith('')),
    ]).pipe(
      map(([configs, searchValue]) => {
        return configs.filter((config: any) =>
          config.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue),
        );
      }),
      tap((configs) => {
        (this.integration.controls['pages'] as FormArray).clear();

        configs.forEach((x: any) =>
          (this.integration.controls['pages'] as FormArray).push(
            this.setupPageForm(x),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }

  setupPageForm(config: any): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(config.id || null, {
        nonNullable: true,
      }),
      name: new FormControl(config.name || '', {
        nonNullable: true,
        validators: [Validators.required],
      }),
      block_id: new FormControl(config.block_id || '', {
        nonNullable: true,
        validators: [Validators.required],
      }),
    });
  }
}
```

*config-list.component.html* Changes:

1. A root element with `formArrayName="pages"` attribute.
2. Add `[formGroupName]="i"` attribute to the `<app-config>`.
3. Remove the `[controlGroup]` attribute.

```
<ng-container formArrayName="pages">
  <h1 *ngFor="let config of (configs | async); let i = index">{{config.name}} 
    <app-config
      [formGroupName]="i"
      [config]="config"
      >
    </app-config>
  </h1>
</ng-container>
```

*config.component.ts* Changes:

1. Remove the `controlGroup` `@Input` variable.
2. Remove the logic to add `FormGroup` into the `FormArray`.

```
export class ConfigComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  public config!: any;

  public pageControl: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setupForm();
  }

  /**
   * to set up form
   * @protected
   */
  protected setupForm(): void {
    this.pageControl = new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(this.config.id || null, {
        nonNullable: true,
      }),
      name: new FormControl(this.config.name || '', {
        nonNullable: true,
        validators: [Validators.required],
      }),
      block_id: new FormControl(this.config.block_id || '', {
        nonNullable: true,
        validators: [Validators.required],
      }),
    });
  }
}
```

[Demo @ Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/wonderful-james-fdjly2-forked-tczyq4?file=%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fconfig-lists%2Fconfig-lists.component.ts%3A33%2C39&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsuby629000628686izgtrde%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsuby6290002286864a1qb9v%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsuby62900042868wkmdu4jg%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsuby62900052868bhy6hjgh%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B60.112229868891994%252C39.887770131108006%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clsuby6290002286864a1qb9v%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsuby6290002286864a1qb9v%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt0x27qb0002356h2tk3fxmn%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A33%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A39%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A33%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A39%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fapp%252Fconfig-lists%252Fconfig-lists.component.ts%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt0x27qb0002356h2tk3fxmn%2522%257D%252C%2522clsuby62900052868bhy6hjgh%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsuby62900052868bhy6hjgh%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A4200%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsufx0yn012q2867ifhusrpn%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsufx0yn012q2867ifhusrpn%2522%257D%252C%2522clsuby62900042868wkmdu4jg%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsuby62900042868wkmdu4jg%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsuby629000328688wpfue8w%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsuby629000328688wpfue8w%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)